# Aligning elements using Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get an understanding of flex and vertically aligning text.  I know there are a lot of posts out there, and I've been reading W3Docs articles, but still can't seem to grasp the concepts.

Take the example below.  I would like to vertically align the number 1 in the first box.  And also I would like the boxes to flow to the left, but also up to fill in the empty space that is left by box 1.

Can someone please dumb this down for me so I can understand?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER */
        display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+*/
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width: 700px;
      }
      .box {
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        height: fit-content;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: steelblue;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box" style="height: 400px">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you wanting 2 - 6 in one column next to the 1?  If so, you're probably better using grid, unless 1 is a fixed height, then you would need to change the flex direction and add that height to the container

Comment: To get them all the same height, remove `height: fit-content` on `.box`. To do the other things, add this to `.box`: `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`.

Comment: aligning "1" inside that box has nothing to do with the flex you're using, because `display:flex;` is one the container and the concerned flex-items are the boxes.
"1" is inside of the box so it has nothing to do with the CSS you're using

Comment: if it's to use as a page structure, better to use grid than flex. Grid is a 2 axis structure, after in a cell you can use flex.

Comment: _"And also I would like the boxes to flow to the left, but also up to fill in the empty space that is left by box 1"_ - flexbox is a row-based layout system, but now you want to _break up_ the rows, and show elements in places other than the row where they are supposed to be ... So you rather don't actually want flexbox then, it is not very suitable for that kind of task.

Comment: Pete - the boxes may actually vary in height and size, but yes that is the main idea.  I want things to flow to the left and up to fill in any gaps.

Comment: ralph.m - I will give this a try.

Comment: AJ Zack - you're absolutely right.  This is a two-part question.  Trying to figure out both problems.

Comment: pier - interesting...will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the other boxes to go to the right of box 1, a `flex-direction: column;` might be a better fit. You can use `flex-flow: column wrap;` as a shorthand for direction and wrap.

To make both columns flow to the left: `align-content: flex-start;`

To make the right column items spread evenly from top to bottom: `justify-content: space-between;`

To vertically center box contents: make the boxes flow containers as well, and justify:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Would this be your desired result?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER */
        display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+*/
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        max-height: 400px;
        align-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .box {
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        height: fit-content;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: steelblue;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box" style="height: 400px"><p>1</p></div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks drak.  I think this is very close, if not exactly what I was looking for. I'll need to study this a bit more.  In my actual project, I am building a mega-menu for our website, and want to try to eliminate dead space between menu section when the page is resized.  I think what you've done here might work.  I'll test this a bit more and if so, mark this as the answer.  Thanks!